# Inehritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

Suppose I have the following code which run without any compilation/runtime errors:

```
B b1 = new A();
B b2 = new C();
A a1 = (C) b2;
D d1 = new C();
B b3 = new B();
D d2 = new A();
D d3 = new B();
E e1 = new E();
D e2 = new E();
B e3 = new E();
C c1 = new C();
```

I need to figure out the relationship between the classes.
As far as I can understand:

```
(head) D <- B <- A <- C
```

Two questions I have:

1. Where do I place `E` ? can it be anywhere in `B / A / C` ?
2. Why when I set `Object var = new A();` and then try `((C)var).someMethod();` I get run time error saying `Class A can not be cast to class C` ? From my experience so far I can only downcast in java (correct?). If I try to swap `A` and `C` I get compilation error with `A a1 = (C) b2;` so I guess `C` must inherit from `A` ?

Comment: Is this some kind of puzzle you're trying to solve?

Comment: As of your runtime-error it´s pretty obvious. An instance of `C` is an instance of `A`, not the other way. Thus you can´t cast `A` to `C`, but `C` to `A`.

Comment: @Sweeper , no it's a question from past exam which I don't have the answers for. @HimBromBeere , so basically you say an instance of `A` can have pointer of `B / D / Object` only, correct?

Comment: B>A,  B>C,   D>C,  D>A,  A>C, D>B,  D>E,  B>E    Hence:  D <- B <-  (E,   A <- C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Included @Sweeper's comments in the image.

> Where do I place E ? can it be anywhere in B / A / C ?

With the code you have given, any of the following hierarchies is possible.

[image]

> I get run time error saying `Class A can not be cast to class C`

This is because you can case an instance of a child class to its parent type but not the other way. So, you cannot cast and instance of `A` to `C`. The following points may give a sense why:

1. A child class contains all the structural parts of a parent class that are `protected` or more visible (even package access), but the converse is not true.
2. Due to this reason, a parent class reference can completely represent itself when pointing to a child class instance. So, the compiler can allow this.
3. When a child type reference points to a parent class instance, then some of the structural parts of the reference (child) are missing in the parent, and hence, the child class reference cannot be completely represented by the referred object. Hence, the compiler will not allow this.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for answering! Im not sure about something though. If I have an instance of `B` with a pointer of `A` . Does it mean I can **upcast** it to have a pointer of `B` ?

Comment: Aren't there two more possibilities you haven't mentioned? `E` being between `C` and `A`, and being between `B` and `A`.

Comment: @bm1125 I am not sure if I understood the term **upcast**. Do you mean ```A a = new B(); B b = (B) a;```? In the hierarchy being discussed, that is not possible. So, reversing it, we get ```B b = new A(); A a = (A) b;```. Yes, this is certainly possible. I have edited the answer and attempted some explanation to visualize casting in which direction works and why.

Answer (score 1):

1. It seems like `E` is not part of the inheritance tree (as much as we can tell) since there's no casting to or from it. Therefore personally I would leave it out - but that depends on the question definition that you try to solve.
2. In your case, you've created an instance of the object 'A' and then tried to cast it into the object `C` - the runtime error indicates that `A` is not an instance of `C` (meaning that `A` does not inherit from `C`).